# Relocate profiles to new server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, user-profile

We have a Windows Server 2008 that is part of our domain. Users access this server using their domain accounts.
Now we have new server with Windows Server 2008 R2 and we want to move the users' profiles from the old server to the new server and when the user log in with his domain account to the new server, he/she should have all his documents that where in the old server.

What is the best way to move the profiles to the new server.

We have a bout 60 profiles.

We are non-profit organization so we prefer free solution.

Regards.

Comment: So they are already set up as roaming profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are roaming profiles you wont need to migrate them as they will be accessed from wherever you store profiles when the user logs in the first time on the new server.

If they aren't roaming profiles, you can use a tool like robocopy and copy them from C:\Users\ to the the new server's C:\Users making sure to copy permissions as well.  Will probably want various other robocopy switches as well read the robocopy documentation linked.

`robocopy \\server1\c$\users  \\server2\c$\users /copyall`

[Robocopy Doc](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)